# Off-topic closure: why so few specific reasons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, off-topic

I just found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281927/blank-page-is-inserted-at-the-beginning-of-the-thesis) through review -- a first post. The question is perfectly clear: the user has a problem and is asking for a solution. So it is not `unclear what you're asking`. I cannot say it is `too broad` since I do not know how broad it might be because there are no details, and it certainly doesn't seem that broad. I cannot say `spam` because it decidedly isn't. It doesn't seem `primarily opinion-based` and I do not know of anything it is a `duplicate of`. So I go under `off-topic` and I find:

[image]

WHAT?? Where is `missing context` and all the other reasons present on Math SX? Should I leave it open? Should I choose `too broad` because an answer as of now would be guesswork? Why do we only have these two specific off-topic reasons? I believe the others at Math are pretty useful:

[image]

So where have they gone? Were they ever present here? Why were they removed if they were? Can we have them back?

**Update**

Joseph points out `missing context` is not `off-topic`, but still I think we should have that close reason. This way a question without context can be closed as such, so the poster will perhaps be incentivize to add this context.

Comment: But it's not off-topic: if it stays as it is it might be considered unclear at some stage in the future.

Comment: Perhaps `missing context` should be an independent reason then. I agree that having `missing context` under `off-topic` seems strange, but it is better than not having it.

Comment: BTW, don't you see the 'Other' off-topic close option (I'm guessing not)? I get three possible options, and the last one allows free text.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't show up in flagging, which is what I am doing from the First Post queue. [This is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lkgp8.png).

Comment: Went for `I'm done` for now, might flag it in the future.

Comment: As it stands, the question is unclear, since the problem is not reproducable. But usually, questions (other than spam/off-topic) stay open quite a while here. if they don't find an answer and can't be answered, they will be dealt with in a *answer the unanswered* session in the future.